# get transit time with GTFS on Python

Tags: python, graph, networkx, gtfs

I need to create/get an algorithm to find the shortest route between two stops using GTFS files in Python.
I've already found the `partridge`, `peartree` and `networkx` libraries. However, I need more explanations or documentations about converting a GTFS to a time dependant graph. Obviously, I need to find the fastest way to compute the shortest route.

Any advice on what I should look for ? Other libraries, articles etc.